# How can I center my table in the middle of a two-column document?

Tags: tables, center

I want to center my table in the middle of a two-column document in Latex. I have tried the {table*} and "\centering" command and it works, but not completely. It left aligns the table instead of centering it across the two columns. Here is my code. I would appreciate any tips on how to center this table properly.

```
\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{Monte Carlo Simulation Results vs. Historical Food Distributions}
\label{table:DistributionComparison}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llllcll@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Simulation} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Historical} & Difference between means &        &                  \\ \midrule
$M_1$            & $(SD_1)$           & $M_2$             & $(SD_2)$            & $M_1$ - $M_2$ {[}95\% CI{]}    & $t(460)$  & $p$                \\ \midrule
146,797          & (3,786)          & 122,468           & (27,411)           & 24,330 {[}21,080, 27,578{]}    & 14.7132  & \textless{}0.001 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
\item Note. $ N=462$. CI = Confidence Interval; $n_1 = 450$. $n_2 = 12$. 
\end{tablenotes}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: Please post a complete document (a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)) that demonstrates the problem. Don't make us guess what packages and document class you're using. When I test your code in the standard article class with the twocolumn option, the table is centered between the columns, so there must be more in your actual document that's relevant.

Comment: I am using the \documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc} and the \usepackage{booktabs,caption}, \usepackage{multicol}, and \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

Comment: Don't put code in the comments. Edit the question and add the code to the code block, making it compiliable as is.

Comment: But isn't the problem just the natural result of the `flushleft` option to threeparttable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided the full code to compile and test so I am guessing the annotation are moved left because table itself should be centred.

First, the `table*` environment creates space of the full width but your table is is not that wide. I never used `tablesnotes` this way and I guess because it is not a part of the table, it is moved to the left margin with a small indentation as `tablesnotes` create a list.

If you want annotation to be aligned with the table, remove `tablesnotes` and either insert one more row below `\bottomrule` with all cells merged

```
 \multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{\small Note. ...}
```

or apply `threeparttable` as in the example below, which I would recommend

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\kant[1-4]

\begin{table*}
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Monte Carlo Simulation Results vs. Historical Food Distributions}
    \label{table:DistributionComparison}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}llllcll@{}}
      \toprule
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{Simulation}
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Historical}
      & Difference between means
      & & \\
      \midrule
      $M_1$   & $(SD_1)$ & $M_2$   & $(SD_2)$ & $M_1$ - $M_2$ {[}95\% CI{]} & $t(460)$ & $p$ \\
      \midrule
      146,797 & (3,786)  & 122,468 & (27,411) & 24,330 {[}21,080, 27,578{]} & 14.7132  & $<0.001$ \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    {\small Note. $ N=462$. CI = Confidence Interval; $n_1 = 450$. $n_2 = 12$.}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table*}

\kant[2-5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!  The threeparttable worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

[image]

With `taltblr` table, which is `tabularray` equivalent for `threeparttable` and use of the `stfloat` package, you can get table centered at the top or at the bottom of the page (if it is inserted in the first column and after this point is enough space for table):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{table*}[b]
  \centering
    \begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Monte Carlo Simulation Results vs. Historical Food Distributions},
  label = {table:DistributionComparison},
note{} = {Note: $ N=462$, CI = Confidence Interval, $n_1 = 450$, $n_2 = 12$.}
                    ]{colspec = {@{} *{7}{Q[c, mode=math]} @{}},
                      row{1}  = {c, mode=text}
                      }
    \toprule
\SetCell[c=2]{c}   Simulation 
    &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}   Historical 
            &   &   Difference between means
                    &   &   \\
    \cmidrule[r]{1-2}
    \cmidrule[lr]{3-4}
    \cmidrule[lr]{5-5}
M_1     & (SD_1)    & M_2       & (SD_2)    & M_1 - M_2\ [95\,\% CI]    & t(460)    & p \\
    \midrule
146,797 & (3,786)   & 122,468   & (27,411)  & 24,330\ [21,080, 27,578]  & 14.7132   & <0.001 \\
146,797 & (3,786)   & 122,468   & (27,411)  & 24,330\ [21,080, 27,578]  & 14.7132   & <0.001 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{talltblr}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[3-6]
\end{document}
```